# Is there a way to exit the current view group while using pan gesture in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, storyboard

So I have a horizontal scroll view at the bottom of my screen which contains child views. I would like to drag a view from the bottom and snap it to a defined position on the top. But while dragging the view, it only moves about inside the scroll view. Is there any way to exit the scrollview and get the view outside it?

Layout of the app (I want to take the items from the bottom and snap them to the positions on top):
[image: layout of the app. I want to take the items from the bottom and snap them to the positions on top]

Answer (score 0):

When you try moving views coordinates with drag, it will only move on its superview, i.e. your bottom scroll view.

If you wanted to drag your button outside of your scroll view then you need to have a trick here.

1. When user started dragging the button, hide it.
2. Add the same layout button on main screen on exact position.
3. Move the newly added button on main screen where ever you want.
4. Once you drop it, remove the old scroll view button.

It will look like you dragged the same button on main screen but under the hood it was a different logic.